# String to Int for new patient ID

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, string, visual-studio-2010

I need to convert a string in the database of patients to a int to create a new patient ID.

In the Hospital database, the patient ID is a STRING, not an integer.  It is of the form p99.  To create a new ID, I need to take out the p, convert to an integer, add 1, then put a 0 in if the value is less than 10, then add back the p.

I am using Microsoft visual studio and C#.
How would I go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) Method and [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method.

**String.Substring Method (Int32)**

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position.

**Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)**

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.

```
string patientId = "p99";
int id;
if (Int32.TryParse(patientId.Substring(1), out id))
{
    patientId = string.Format("p{0}{1}", id < 10 ? "0" : string.Empty, id);
    MessageBox.Show("Patient Id : " + patientId);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error while retrieving the patient id.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.Parse()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx)) to convert a string to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple routine to do this.

Assuming there is always a leading 'p' you can just do sID = sID.substring(1) to remove the first character.
Then you can use  Int ID = Int16.Parse(sID) to convert to an Int (16-bit in this case).  If you need 32-bit, use Int32.Parse

then ID++ or ID = ID+1 to increment by one.

Next, you need to convert back to a string with sID = ID.ToString()

Finally, do some string manipulation to test the length, add the leading '0' if length = 1, and the leading 'p'.